# Rules to discard photos

Tags: practice

How to discard old photos and idols in a dignified manner? Please give authentic suggestion with support from scriptures.

Comment: I'm not sure about pictures, but I think there are procedures for properly disposing of old idols in the Agamas.

Comment: Does the instructions holds good for **all** the idols which is kept in  puja room

Comment: I  asked my Guruji the same question since i had accumulated a lot of images of Gods and i was not able to worship them all.I asked whether i can immerse them in river?And he said yes you can and  that is the  recommended process for images/idols of Gods that you can't worship daily.So,i immersed all such images in the Ganges.

Answer (score -2):

> Fire is considered as the most pious above all. You can definitely
>   burn the torn photographs.
>
> If there is anything solid left like frames or statues you can put
>   them in any lake or river, like विसर्जन .
>
> [Reference Source](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-dispose-Hindu-God-photo-frames-idols-etc-without-any-pollution)

Comment: Quora is not authentic source to cite. Please cite Smriti or Shruti or discourses of Acharyas.

Comment: @ freekundli please support your answer with reference to puranas or smiriti.